# Calculate min/max values for signed or unsigned integral number with any valid number of bits (up to 64)

Tags: c#

This came up when I answered another post.

Is there a better way?

```
public class Bits
{
    public static void MinMaxI(ulong _bits, out long _min, out long _max)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        _min = (long)1 << (int)(_bits - 1);
        _max = -1 - _min;
    }


    public static long MinI(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return (long)1 << (int)(_bits - 1);
    }


    public static long MaxI(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return -1 - ((long)1 << (int)(_bits - 1));
    }


    public static ulong MaxN(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 1 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("1 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return _bits == 64 ? ~(ulong)0 : ~(~(ulong)0 << (int)_bits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Underscore notation for parameters - that's something I've not seen before.

Comment: ... and `name_` for locals, since parameters are assigned before locals - so underscore before name == assigned before and underscore after name == assigned after. And no underscore for members. But Nick, these are not my real work coding conventions - but I'm afraid that people would freak out here if I would use them ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think there are misprints in your code that maximums are negative and minimums are positive.

Next. Since you need `MinI`, `MaxI` and `MaxN` values for a few bits only, it makes sense to calculate these values apriory. In this case we can use loop for calculation.
In the following code I've used recurrent formulas for calculation, which are much more readable in my opinion:

```
public class Bits
{
    public const int MaxBits = 64;

    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<long> MinI;
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<long> MaxI;
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ulong> MaxN;

    static Bits()
    {
        long[] minI = new long[MaxBits + 1];
        long[] maxI = new long[MaxBits + 1];
        ulong[] maxN = new ulong[MaxBits + 1];

        maxN[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < MaxBits; i++)
        {
            maxI[i] = maxI[i - 1] * 2 + 1;
            minI[i] = -maxI[i] - 1;
            maxN[i] = maxN[i - 1] * 2 + 1;
        }

        maxI[MaxBits] = long.MaxValue;
        minI[MaxBits] = long.MinValue;
        maxN[MaxBits] = ulong.MaxValue;

        MinI = new ReadOnlyCollection<long>(minI);
        MaxI = new ReadOnlyCollection<long>(maxI);
        MaxN = new ReadOnlyCollection<ulong>(maxN);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(Bits.MinI[3]);
Console.WriteLine(Bits.MaxI[3]);
Console.WriteLine(Bits.MaxN[3]);
```

Output:

```
-4
3
7
```

The only difference in functionality I can see is that arrays have values for bits `0` and `1`.
Hope it is not a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A good point is the constant for maxbits. I didn't find any misprints in my code were maximums are negative or minimums or positive. Could you please give me a hint? With the bit operations I use the definition of two's complement - which is, IMHO, straight to the point. Beside that, these operations are blazing fast. So there should not be a big difference between a checked array access and my range check followed by the bit operations. And, beside having values for bits 0 and 1, you get non-related error message for bits > 64.

Comment: @carpetemporem The hint: return value in the `MinI` is `(long)1 << (int)(_bits - 1)` which is positive. And for the `MaxI` return value is `-1 - MinI` which is negative. They probably should be renamed.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! These formulas are wrong. I only tested the edge case of 64 bit - where they work. `(long)1` must be replaced by `~(long)0` as I it is done in `MaxN`.